# Sharepoint Customize Form substitute string in HTML text

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I have simple problem but cant figure out.

In `Customize Form` I have `HTHML text`. From SharepointList column i got one or more `URL` links separated with `|`. With one Link, HTML text works as Hyperlink. With two or more, doesn't.

`HTML text`

```
Concatenante("<a href='",
    DataCardValue12.Text,
    "'>",
    DataCardValue12.Text,
    "</a>"
)
```

`Source data:`

```
https://company.sharepoint.com/list/pdf1.pdf | https://company.sharepoint.com/list/pdf1.pdf
```

`Concatente with Substitute`

```
Concatenate(Substitute(DataCardValue12.Text," | ", "<br>"),
    "<a href='",
    DataCardValue12.Text,
    "'>",
    DataCardValue12.Text,
    "</a>"
)
```

Not works. Hyperlinks are doubled and not clickable.

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formula like below for `HTMLText` property of HTMLText control:

```
Concat(Split(DataCardValue12.Text, " | "), "<a href='"&ThisRecord.Result&"'>"&ThisRecord.Result&"</a><br>")
```

**Output**:

[image]